# Where the origin of the camera system really is?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

When we compute the pose of the camera with respect to a primitive like a marker or a 3D model..etc, the origin of that primitive is usually precisly known like the origin of a chessboard or a marker (in blue).

[image]

Now the question is where is the origin of the camera (in black)? The vector translation of the pose is expressed with respect to which reference? How can we determine where it is?

Comment: the camera origin (projection center) is always in (0,0,0) unless you choose a different position with your extrinsical camera parameters. The image itself is "placed" in front of the projection center according to your intrinsical camera parameters.

Comment: @Micka Yes but my question was where that origin in real world really is

Comment: in real world there is no origin, you can choose it. By default, the camera center is in the origin, so the real world origin is where your camera projection center is, unless you choose some camera extrinsics.

Comment: So ya where is that camera projection center is :)

Comment: depends on the intrinsical camera parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optical center is meant to be on the optical axis (ideally it projects to the center of the image), at a distance of the sensor equal to the focal length, which can be expressed in pixel units (knowing the pixel size).

You can see where the optical axis lies (it is the symmetry axis of the lens), but the optical center is somewhere inside the camera.

Comment: Where the sensor is? so why we can never know where the optical center is?

Comment: @Ja_cpp: in fact there are two centers. one in object space and one in image space. The latter is at distance f from the sensor; the former is somewhere between the lenses but you don't know exactly where, and it moves when you refocus.

Comment: What those centers are called? Your answer is very interesting, would you have a reference or a figure to visualize that? because you I’m little lost with all the vocabularies

Comment: @Ja_cpp: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_point_(optics)#Nodal_points

Comment: That looks like more difficult than I thought, I’ll try to dig in deep to understand more how it works

Comment: @Ja_cpp: don't worry, you actually *never* need to locate these points physically. You obtain their relative positions by solving the stereo equations.

Comment: What is the stereo equations? You mean when I’ve two cameras?

Comment: @Ja_cpp: ok, say the calibration equations.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV uses the [pinhole camera model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model) to model cameras. The origin of the 3D coordinate system used in OpenCV, for camera calibration and other purposes, is the camera itself, or more specifically, the pinhole of the camera model. It is the point where all light rays that enter the camera converge to a point, and is also called the "centre of projection".

Real cameras with lenses do not actually have a pinhole.  But by analysing images taken with the camera, it is possible to calculate a pinhole model which models the real camera's optics very closely.  That is what OpenCV does when it calibrates your camera. As @Yves Daoust said, the pinhole of this model (and hence the 3D coordinate origin) will be a 3D point somewhere inside your camera (or possibly behind it, depending on its focal length), but it is not possible for OpenCV to say exactly where it is relative to your camera's body, because OpenCV knows nothing about the physical size or shape of your camera or its sensor.

Even if you knew exactly where the origin is relative to your camera's body, it probably would not be of much use, because you can't take any physical measurements with respect to a point that is located inside your camera without taking it apart! Really, you can do everything you need to do in OpenCV without knowing this detail.

Comment: Well I might not agree with you in the last paragraph because if you’re interested in computing the pose, you need to know the references in the physical world where your translation and rotation are expressed

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree :-) OpenCV can tell you the pose of an AR marker with respect to your camera; the pose of your camera is simply the inverse of that transform. If you know the coordinates and orientation of the marker in the physical world (in some coordinate system), you can concatenate transforms to get your camera pose in the same coordinate system.

Comment: Well that’s not what I mean.. I know that the poses are equivalent camera to marker or marker to camera but my disagreement is about the camera reference and where it is exactly in the physical world that the issue involved by the whole post